# JavaScript wrapper to have current position available

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm working on Javascript that is geared towards mobile browsers. The goal is to save the current geo location every few seconds.

There is no system.getPosition or something to get the current position at any given time. To get the position, you can use navigator.geolocation.getPosition(function x) where function x is a function that will be called with a position object as argument, whenever the position becomes available. The other option is to use navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function x), where function x will be called with a position object as argument every time the position changes.

I'd like something where I can get the current geo position from at any given time.

This works:

```
var _position;
function setPosition(position) {
    _position = position;
}
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(setPosition);
```

_position always holds the latest position.

Why doesn't this work? I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_position' of undefined":

```
class GPS {
    constructor(){
        var _position;      //fields in javascript are defined by the
    }                       //constructor

    setPosition(position) {
        this._position = position;
    }

    getPosition(){
        return this._position;
    }
}

gps = new GPS();
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(gps.setPosition);
```

Comment: You aren't defining an object property, you're defining a local variable in the constructor.

Comment: So is their no way to define a field in JS? I'm coming from Java, and am getting really confused by what I find on Google.

Comment: You can, it just doesn't work the same as in Java. Have a look at [MDN's page on the `class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). I would also recommend reading about [using a constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) and defining methods on the prototype, because the newer `class` syntax is basically doing that for you behind the scenes.

Comment: P.S. You're going to get *really* confused if you don't read about [how `this` works in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Sometimes it will be what you expect with your Java background, but other times it will not. The way JS handles these things is good, just *different* to Java. Each way has its place.